# What is """ in python?

Tags: python

My code:

```
 """
 def
 """
 k="""
 abc
 """
 print(k)
 print('abc2')
```

I try to run it:

```
  sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$ python test.py 

  abc

  abc2
  sam@sam-M51Kr:~/code/python$
```

In the beginning of code, it seems """ become a comment.

But why k is two empty line with 'abc'?

Thank you~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

""" is a string delimiter.

From [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.

Thus your string just after the method is a comment and can be used by other tools to document your code. If you use an unassigned string literal elsewhere it is just a comment to help those reading the code (except in a couple of cases mentioned in the previous link)

From the [python reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

> In triple-quoted strings, unescaped newlines and quotes are allowed (and are retained), except that three unescaped quotes in a row terminate the string. (A “quote” is the character used to open the string, i.e. either ' or ".)

Thus includes the carriage returns/line feeds.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** "But why k is two empty line with 'abc'?"

```
k="""
 abc
 """
```

the `"""` (also `'''`) is a multi-line string delimiter that ***preserves*** the *newlines*, so there's a newline after the initial `"""`, and one after the `abc` which is why you get the blank lines.

Using `repr()` you can see this explicitly:

```
repr(k)
"'\\n abc\\n '"
```

`"""` is used to write long, multi-line, strings, or as a documentation aid in the form of a [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) (or [this](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/docstrings.html)) as you also correctly noted.

Answer (score 1):

`""" ... """` is just a multi-line string. So

```
"""
abc
"""
```

is a newline, then `abc` then another newline.

Answer (score 1):

The first unassigned string of any object, in this case a module, is called the "docstring". It automatically gets assigned to the special variable `__doc__` in the scope where it's defined.

The other is a multi-line string. These are "as-is" strings that preserve the embedded newline characters. So the first line, that assigns `k`, has a newline at the beginning and end of the string. You don't normally see it in a terminal.